# How to find the del of spherical vector field?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, spherical-coordinates

Given $\vec{v}=wr\vec{i}_{\theta}-v_0\vec{i}_r$

How do I solve $\nabla\cdot \vec{v}$ and $\nabla\times\vec{v}?$

Comment: What formulas do you know for div and rot?

Comment: I know that for div: $\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2A_v)+....+$ but I don't know how to use them properly. I'm totally lost.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $\nabla = (\partial/\partial\theta, \partial/\partial r)$ and that $r$ and $\theta$ are independent of each other, you note that
$$
\begin{split}
\nabla \cdot \vec{v}
 &= \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}, \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)
    \cdot (wr, -v_0) \\
 &= \frac{\partial [wr]}{\partial\theta} + \frac{\partial[-v_0]}{\partial r} \\
 &= r \frac{\partial w}{\partial\theta} - \frac{\partial v_0}{\partial r}
\end{split}
$$
and everything else will depend on how $w$ and $v_0$ depend on $r$ and $\theta$.

If you are using polar coordinates, note that
$$
\nabla = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r}, \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right)
$$

Can you complete this and find the curl in a similar way?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using polar coordinates, so you could have a look at the following wiki page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formula